# Java: Cannot access object's element

Tags: java, oop

This is a toy example. So, basically I created an ArrayClass object. I instantiate it in another class. But I cannot access its elements. I got this error:

`error: array required, but ArrayClass found`

What am I doing wrong here?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;

public class ArrayClass{
    protected int[] input_array;
    protected int nElems;

    // multiple constructor
    public ArrayClass(){
        // nothing here
    }

    public ArrayClass(int max){
        input_array = new int [max];
        nElems = 0;
    }

    public void insert(int value){
        input_array[nElems++] = value;
    }
}

class ArrayApp{
    public static void main(String[] args){      
            ArrayClass input_array = new ArrayClass(len);         
            for(int i = 0; i <= 10; i++){
                System.out.println(input_array[i]);
            }
}
```

Comment: You could access the array in your `ArrayClass` with `input_array.input_array[i]`. Where the first`input_array` is the instance of your `ArrayClass` and the second `.input_array` is the actual array with the same name in that class

Comment: FYI: `len` is not defined and in your for-loop you should also use the same `len` variable and not a constant value. Secondly, I think it would be more appropriate to add a `get(int index)` method to your `ArrayClass` where you return the `input_array[index]` element. so that you can access it in your `main` method like this: `input_array.get(i)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My comments in a proper answer:

```
ArrayClass input_array = new ArrayClass(len);         
for(int i = 0; i <= 10; i++){
    System.out.println(input_array[i]);
}
```

This does not work because here `input_array` is an instance of your class `ArrayClass` (and not an array). Only arrays can be accessed like this: `array[i]`. So if you want to access the array from your `ArrayClass` you could either do:

```
ArrayClass input_array = new ArrayClass(len);         
for(int i = 0; i <= 10; i++){
    System.out.println(input_array.input_array[i]);
}
```

where the first `input_array` is the instance of your `ArrayClass` Object and the second `input_array` is the actual array inside that class (they have the same name, so it may be a little confusing). Generally speaking it would be `myObject.array[i]`.

However, when you define a class like this, it is better to don't allow access to the classes variables but provide methods for that. So your class could look like that:

```
public class ArrayClass {

    private int[] input_array;  // private means that no access is allowed from outside the class
    private int nElems;


    public void insert(int value) {   // here you already provide a method to access the array from outside the class
        input_array[nElems++] = value;
    }

    public int get(int index){    // this would be the method to get the value from your array
       return input_array[index];
    }
}
```

Now you can access the array like this (in your loop for example):

```
input_array.get(i);
```

Providing such getter/setter methods is recommended, since here you can be sure that you control all access to the array and nothing "bad" can happen. Imagine you would write something like this in your `main` method:

```
input_array.input_array = new int[0];
```

Then the array from your `ArrayClass` would be gone and you could no longer guarantee that the `ArrayClass` instance would work.

Answer (score 4):

You are attempting to retrieve an array element with `[]`, but ArrayClass is not an array.  You either need to expose `input_array`, or define a get method to retrieve its contents, for example:

```
public getValue(int index)
{
    return input_array[index];
}
```